# How come my variable seems to lose content I recently added?

Tags: java, key-value

I am trying to add RGB-values to a variable called

```
HashMap<Integer,Couple> basicProvince
```

I do this in the following method:

```
public void initBasicRGB(String definitionCSVContent) {
    System.out.println("initBasicRGB");
    String[] lines = definitionCSVContent.split("\n");
    String[] values;
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : lines) {
        values = s.split(";");
        if (!s.isEmpty() && values.length == 6 && i != 0 && !values[0].equals("")) {
            int red = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            int green = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
            int blue = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
            if (basicProvince.get(Integer.parseInt(values[0])) != null) {
                basicProvince.get(Integer.parseInt(values[0])).setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (Entry<Integer, Couple> e : basicProvince.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key = " + e.getKey() + "\t value= " + e.getValue().getName() + " " + e.getValue().getColor());
    }
}
```

All the output displays everything as it should be. 
Example:

```
key = 8  value= breifne java.awt.Color[r=126,g=24,b=4]
```

Than immediately after this method ,I call the next one below which is supposed to use information from this variable and use that info in

```
c.setBasicRGB(e.getValue().getColor());

    public void giveCountyBasicRGB() {
    String name = "";
    System.out.println("give county basicRGB");
    for (Entry<Integer, Couple> e : basicProvince.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key = " + e.getKey() + "\t value= " + e.getValue().getName() + " " + e.getValue().getColor());
    }

    for (County c : countyList) {
        name = c.getName();
        for (Entry<Integer, Couple> e : basicProvince.entrySet()) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getValue().getName())) {
                System.out.println("color " + e.getValue().getColor() + " name " + e.getValue().getName());
                // here you can see the line that retrieves the info
                c.setBasicRGB(e.getValue().getColor());
            }
        }

        if (c.getBasicRGB() == null) {
            System.out.println("Warning: " + c.getName() + " does not have a basic rgb");
        }
    }
}
```

The odd thing is that my first method shows me a proper color with the following piece of code.

```
       for (Entry<Integer, Couple> e : basicProvince.entrySet()) {
           System.out.println("key = " + e.getKey() + "\t value= " +  e.getValue().getName() + " " + e.getValue().getColor());
       }
```

While the moment my second method runs the same piece of code in her body.

I get a null for

```
e.getValue().getColor()
```

Even though I have just added that information in the first method.

Thank you for your time and my apologies if some things aren't clear enough.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a short but *complete* program demonstrating the program, rather than multiple snippets.

Comment: can you provide your `Couple` class? how did you return `getColor()`  and `setBasicRGB()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code right, the variable "e" seems local to the for loops and when you try to pass it as a parameter to the SetBasicRGB function the value is gone.
Maybe using another more variable defined outside the for loop?